# How to show a calculation in the array in Laravel?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I want to show the balances of the companies one after another in the "Businesses" page in a pre-accounting software.

Below is an example I made on the "account-detail.blade.php" page.

What's the easiest way to do this on the "accounts-index.blade.php" page? (Multiple calculations.)

Thank you.

---

AccountDetailsController.php -> Correctly working code block.

```
    $sales_and_payments = Invoice::where('account_id', $id)
        ->whereIn('type', ['payment', 'sales'])
        ->sum('amount');

    $buys_and_incomes = Invoice::where('account_id', $id)
        ->whereIn('type', ['buying', 'income'])
        ->sum('amount');

    $balance = $sales_and_payments - $buys_and_incomes;
```

---

account-details.blade.php

```
<th scope="col" class="text-center text-primary">
     <i class="nav-icon fas fa-balance-scale mr-1"></i>BAKİYE <br>
     <label class="text-lg">{{ number_format($balance, 2,',','.') }} ₺</label>
</th>
```

account-details.blade.php - https://pasteboard.co/IS3nlVK0.jpg 
  accounts-index.blade.php - https://pasteboard.co/IS3nGJi.jpg

Comment: Please don't add code as images but post the relevant snippets as a code block.

Comment: Ok. I'am adding.

Comment: PASTE not link!

Comment: How do I show the balance on the page with all accounts?